# How to get the Nth LineString from a MultiLineString in PostGIS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need a way to get the Nth LineString from a MultiLineString in PostGIS / PostgreSQL, something like [ST_PointN](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointN.html) that gets the Nth point from a LineString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostGIS function:

```
ST_GeometryN(a_geom geometry, dimension int)
```